# Do ear wax cleaning salons provide related, similar services?

Tags: japan, hygiene

Do ear wax cleaning salons in Japan provide any related, similar services, such as trimming of ear hairs?

Just to clarify, I'm after actual hygiene related services, rather than [karaoke, dating, getting your face slapped](http://en.rocketnews24.com/2015/05/25/mimi-kaki-we-let-a-total-stranger-stick-stuff-inside-us-at-an-ear-cleaning-salon) or anything under the counter.

Comment: Why the down votes?

Comment: There are earwax cleaning salons in Japan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, they provide these services, depending on the salons.**

I have never tried these salons but just [searched on Google quickly in Japanese](https://www.google.com/#q=%E8%80%B3%E3%81%8B%E3%81%8D%E5%B0%82%E9%96%80%E5%BA%97+%E6%AF%9B%E3%82%AB%E3%83%83%E3%83%88), it got many results saying they offer such services as trimming, massages, and applying moisture cleam.

However, I feel that most people in these salons don't get used to foreigners and are very poor at English; even the basic word or conversation such as "hair trimming" might not be understood. I encourage you to memorize some Japanese phrases to ask these services.

For example, *"ke mo katto shi te ku da sai"* may be enough (meaning *"please trim the hair as well"*).